# Html content panel slide in

Tags: jquery, html, slide, nav

Im looking to create an effect something similar to what is seen here

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/42436.html

When a button on the nav bar is pressed the content slides in from the left hand side and rests in the center, when another button is pressed the new content does the same and the old content box leaves on the right hand side. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I tried making this by using a large slider but the navigation was off so any suggestion would be a huge bonus!

Comment: Maybe [this](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html) will help

Comment: I suggest using CSS3 animations as they will be much faster than jquery.  Basically add the class that animates the div to move in from the left and add a class to the current one that animates the div to move to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the menus correspondent divs in the same order as the menu items and give each of them divs same class, and css properties (width, height, position: absolute), then use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.active').css('left', ($(window).width() - $('.active').outerWidth())/2);  
$('li').click(function(){
var ind = $(this).index(),
    activeSlide = $('.active'),    
    slide = $('.slide').eq(ind);
    if(!slide.hasClass('active')){
   slide.stop().animate({'left': ($(window).width() - slide.outerWidth()) / 2}, 300);
        activeSlide.animate({'left': $(window).width()}, 300, function(){
            activeSlide.css('left', - activeSlide.outerWidth());
        });
        activeSlide.removeClass('active');
        slide.addClass('active');   
    }
});        
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.active').css('left', ($(window).width() - $('.active').outerWidth()) / 2);
});                  
});
```

see the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/LTEqJ/) here for more details about the HTML structure and CSS properties:

Comment: thanks again for your help! just a quick question, what if I wanted to start with a slide already open and in view, what would I change? sorry to bother you again

Comment: add second class active to the div which you want to show at page load and position it using css in jquery at document ready. see the updated code and demo, i also included resize function which you'd probably need when resizing the browser.

Comment: you are welcome :), i updated the demo, now li click change the style of the clicked menu item, see the updated demo if you need this feature or just use the code above if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this is to use the jQuery Plus Anchor plugin.

http://css-plus.com/2011/03/plusanchor-jquery-plugin/